# Erlang/OTP: Changes to the already existing modules

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am working over solution to a problem, which requires changes in one of the functions of module `gb_trees`.

I am getting an error compiling the edited version of `gb_trees`:

```
1> c(gb_trees).
cannot write to .bea#
...
2>
```

What's the way I can make changes and compile an already existing module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably your file is being used by another process. Close all applications, that you're using or restart your OS, then try to recompile.

You're trying to manually load a module , which is a part of Erlang/OTP.

From documentation:

> The Erlang runtime system is
>   protecting you.
>
> The easiest solution is to rename your
>   module, e.g. to mysets.erl. It is also
>   possible to 'un-stick' the directory
>   containing the library module.

See [`code:unstick/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#unstick_dir-1).

Also:

> To prevent accidentally reloading
>   modules affecting the Erlang runtime
>   system itself, the `kernel`, `stdlib` and
>   `compiler` directories are considered
>   **sticky**. This means that the system
>   issues a warning and rejects the
>   request if a user tries to reload a
>   module residing in any of them. The
>   feature can be disabled by using the
>   command line flag `-nostick`.

See [`erl(1)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).

For example:

```
$ erl -nostick
Eshell V5.7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(gb_trees).
{ok,gb_trees}
2> gb_trees:module_info().
[{exports,[{foo,2},{module_info,0},{module_info,1}]},
 {imports,[]},
 {attributes,[{vsn,[338095567601101424197378397768992511838]}]},
 {compile,[{options,[]},
           {version,"4.6.3"},
           {time,{2011,2,3,11,39,53}},
           {source,"/tmp/gb_trees.erl"}]}]
3>
```

You see that we can compile and load the module into VM.

However you could just rename your module `gb_trees` to something like `gb_trees_mine` and use functions it exports:

```
1> gb_trees_mine:foo(13,42).
bar
2>
```